# Static Magnetic field in curved spacetime

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, maxwell-equations

I am trying to solve the Maxwell equations in curved spacetime and I came across this paper [1] which tries to do just that. In this paper, the author explores the gravitational effects in a long solenoid. To do so, he uses cylindrical coordinates $x^0=ct$ and $x^i = (r,\phi,z)$ (where the index $i$ take value between 1 and 3). The metric chosen is
$$ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu = e^{2\alpha-2\psi}(-dt^2+dr^2)+e^{-2\psi}r^2d\phi^2+e^{2\psi}dz^2$$

Sice the paper considers that there is a magnetic field only on the z-axis, the Maxwell equation in curved space can be written as
$$\partial_1 (\sqrt{-g} F^{21}) = 0$$
The proposed solution in the paper is the following (equation 3 in the paper):
$$F^{21} = (-g)^{-1/2} B_0, ~~B = (\frac{g_{22}}{g_{11}})^{1/2}\frac{B_0}{r} = e^{-\alpha}B_0$$
**Here comes then my question:** How did the author reach to this solution? Can somebody help me understand what I have missed?

**Edit:**
Below, I roll out my attempt to reproduce the result. First I start by the relation $F^{21} = (-g)^{-1/2} B_0$, then I lower the indices and substitute by the identity $F_{ij} = -\sqrt{\gamma}\epsilon_{ijk}B^k$ (where $\gamma$ is the 3-d determinant for the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$} defined above) to introduce the magnetic field, so:
$$g^{22}g^{11}F_{21} = - g^{22}g^{11}\sqrt{\gamma}\epsilon_{213}B^3 = g^{22}g^{11}\sqrt{\gamma}B^3 = \frac{B_0}{\sqrt{-g}}$$

Using $g_{\mu\nu}$ matrix elements, we get the following:
$$\sqrt{\gamma} = r e^{\alpha - \psi}$$
$$\sqrt{-g} = r e^{2\alpha - 2\psi}$$
$$g_{11}=e^{2\alpha-2\psi}, ~ g_{22} = r^2 e^{-2\psi}$$

so,

$$B^3 \equiv B = \frac{B_0}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{g_{11}g_{22}}{\sqrt{\gamma}} = B_0 e^{-\alpha + \psi} $$

This result is different from what is found in the paper [1] $B = B_0 e^{-\alpha}$. So again, How did the author reach to this solution? any help is appreciated.

[1] - https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0217732394001465